# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'. Even though requests has already been installed

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

I have installed using: pip install requests yet I continue to get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named requests
```

I uninstalled and reinstalled it yet it is still not fixed. Does anyone know the best way to fix this?

I am using python 2.7

Comment: which version of python you are using?

Comment: If you are using any linux distro it may install python for both admin and user. Try to install using `sudo pip install requests`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I found the solution! I needed to get the source code. I did this by cloning the public repository:

$ git clone git://github.com/psf/requests.git

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install/

I hope this is useful to others.

Comment: Bro, again, which version of pyhton?

Comment: You don't need to clone repo, bro. Use `pip3 install python` in windows, I guess that's your problem

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it didn't work but when I cloned, the error messages went away and it was recognising that I have requests installed. I am just happy that it worked.

Comment: thanks a lot for taking the time to help me  @ShivamJha

Comment: You're welcome, @Elena. At StackOverflow, we grow by helping each other